# Cast dictionary as object in swift (ios)

Tags: ios, swift, casting, dao

I have this function searchMoviesOnJson:

```
func searchMoviesOnJson(imdbTitle: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Dictionary<String, Any>?) -> ()) {

let urlByName: String = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=\(imdbTitle)&type=movie"

//returns a list of movies that contains the title searched
//------------------------------------------------

Alamofire.request(urlByName).responseJSON {
    response in

    switch response.result {

    case .success(let value):
        let moviesJSON = value
        completionHandler(moviesJSON as? Dictionary<String, Any>)

    case .failure(_):
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------
}
```

That gives me this response from api (e.g.: imdbTitle = "arq"):

```
{
Response = True;
Search =     (
            {
        Poster = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjAxODQ2MzkyMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjU3MTE5OTE@._V1_SX300.jpg";
        Title = ARQ;
        Type = movie;
        Year = 2016;
        imdbID = tt5640450;
    },
            {
        Poster = "N/A";
        Title = Arq;
        Type = movie;
        Year = 2011;
        imdbID = tt2141601;
    },
            {
        Poster = "N/A";
        Title = "A.R.Q.";
        Type = movie;
        Year = 2015;
        imdbID = tt3829612;
    }
);
totalResults = 3;
}
```

So I created a this class MovieByTitle

```
class MovieByTitle {

var poster : String?
var title  : String?
var year   : Int?
var imdbID : String?

init(poster: String?, title: String?, year: Int?, imdbID: String?) {

    //validation

    if let isPoster = poster { self.poster = isPoster }
    else { self.poster = nil }

    if let isTitle = title { self.title = isTitle }
    else { self.title = nil }

    if let isYear = year { self.year = isYear }
    else { self.year = nil }

    if let isImdbID = imdbID { self.imdbID = isImdbID }
    else { self.imdbID = nil }

}
}
```

And now my doubt, I also create this MovieDAO:

class MovieDao {

```
func getMovies(imdbTitle: String, completionHandler: @escaping (([MovieByTitle]) -> ())) {

    //function that conects to the api
    searchMoviesOnJson(imdbTitle: imdbTitle, completionHandler: {
       moviesJSON in

        //array to keep the attributes received by the dictionary
        var moviesArray = [MovieByTitle]()

        //searchResults is the response from my request as an array
        if let searchResults = moviesJSON?["Search"] as? NSArray{

            for searchResult in searchResults {

                let movieResult = searchResult as! Dictionary<String,Any>
                let movieDetail = MovieByTitle()

                movieDetail.poster = movieResult["Poster"] as? String
                movieDetail.title = movieResult["Title"] as? String
                movieDetail.year = movieResult["Year"] as? Int
                movieDetail.imdbID = movieResult["imdbID"] as? String

                moviesArray.append(movieDetail)

            }
        }
    })
  }
}
```

But the xcode returns an error in line:
                    let movieDetail = MovieByTitle()

Error message: missing argument for parameter 'poster' in call (and so on with the others)

What is the right sintax for that? What is the better way to cast my dictionary response as an object?

Comment: you should look into these two links: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON and https://gist.github.com/tailec/ba266afbf77f6079fcf8 . those are the best way to deal with JSON. as for your code- you should pass values to init, if you want empty init, do `init(){}`

Comment: BTW man, your validation code in `MovieByTitle.init` is really accomplishing nothing at all ;-) You can assign those parameters directly to the corresponding instance properties.

Answer (score 1):

You MovieByTitle init function requires 4 parameters that are missing.

Solution 1: Add a secondary init:

```
init() {}
```

Solution 2: Define existing init parameters as optional by giving them default values:

```
init(poster: String? = nil, title: String? = nil, year: Int? = nil, imdbID: String? = nil)
```

Solution 3: Call the existing init with the parameters it needs:

```
let movieDetail = MovieByTitle(poster: movieResult["Poster"] as? String, title: movieResult["Title"] as? String, year: movieResult["Year"] as? Int, imdbID: movieResult["imdbID"] as? String)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your init function requires 4 parameters. You haven't included any. Try the following

```
let poster = movieResult["Poster"] as? String
let title = movieResult["Title"] as? String
let year = movieResult["Year"] as? Int
let imdbID = movieResult["imdbID"] as? String

let movieDetail = MovieByTitle(poster:poster, title:title, year:year, imdbID:imdbDB)
```